# autohotkey: getting characters of a string sent, while typing normally, to stay together

Tags: autohotkey

```
coloured_text:
send {^}%rand%
return

~t::
Random, rand, 1, 3
SetTimer, coloured_text, 500
return

~esc::
~enter::
SetTimer, coloured_text, Off
return
```

Code: When "t" is pressed the variable RAND gains a random number from 1-3. A label is then called 0.5 seconds later. This label sends the text "^%RAND%" i.e. ^1. The Label repeats every .5 seconds until enter/esc is hit. While all of this is happening though, as soon as I press "t", I am also manually typing sentences out i.e. *"Big red dog"*.

So a good output might looks like: **"Bi^1g red ^3dog".*
But sometimes I get somethin like: **"Bi^g1 red ^do3g".*

In other words I need the label to send the two characters of "{^}%rand%" i.e. "^1" without breaks/gaps. And I need this to be done without interfering with my normal typing, whatever I may be typing. And I can't use any of the other sends (sendinput sendplay sendevent), just normal send.

Comment: Why can't you use `SendInput`? Does the game you're trying to use this for (some CoD?) not work with `SendInput`?

Answer (score 0):

That looks like color control codes of IRC, you can use something like this either via hotkey or hotstring.

It creates a small Gui with just an `Edit` so you can input the text you want colorized and when you press enter every 3 characters (configurable) get a random color.

If you still like your approach, you can take a look into `BlockInput` <sup>[docs](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/BlockInput.htm)</sup> and wrap `Send % "{^}" rand` between them. Is reliable as long as you run the script with [UI Access](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Program.htm#Installer_uiAccess)

```cpp
F1::Colorize()

:*X:/color::Colorize()

Colorize()
{
    Gui C:New, +LastFound -SysMenu
    Gui Add, Edit, -WantReturn r5 w200
    Gui Add, Button, Default Hidden x0 y0, OK
    Gui Show,, Colored Text
}

CButtonOK()
{
    GuiControlGet Line,, Edit1
    Gui Destroy
    Out := "", i := 0
    loop parse, Line
    {
        if (A_LoopField = " ")
        {
            Out .= " "
            continue
        }
        /* Every 3 characters
        */
        if !Mod(i++, 3)
        {
            Random r, 1, 3
            Out .= "{^}" r
        }
        Out .= A_LoopField
    }
    Send % Out
}

CGuiEscape()
{
    Gui Destroy
    ExitApp
}
```

Comment: You'll have to explain what the intent of the code is above and what it's doing. blockinput has pretty mixed results. works okayish for 1second label, doesn't rly work for anything less esp not 500. also fails if u spam

Comment: @kite Thanks for the heads up, regarding `BlockInput` Is pretty reliable and I use it an awful lot, perhaps you need to either run your script with UI Access to let it work system-wide.

Comment: I don't notice any difference between running it as administrator or running it with ui access. It won't function without one of them cause of UAC on my system, I guess that was what you were getting at? I didn't say it wasn't reliable, but these are mixed results for sure cause of what it does. Blockinput is blocking all input. So there are a few things that can happen that are bad: The timing of when I press a key (typing) and when blockinput initiates overlap....and my keystroke isnt sent i.e. "The sky is b^3ue".  i.e. Changing colour every couple keystrokes typing 60+wpm isnt viable.

Comment: Here's another idea, why not just add carets and then complete them with the color number? that way you ensure the proper formatting always. [Example](https://pastebin.com/cbbAdE8v), I also made sure no double color codes were added.